# How parse pyspark column with value as a string to columns

Tags: pyspark

I have the below input table

| id | name | add_info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Messi | Club: PSG, Age: 35, birthplace: Arg |
| 2 | Ronaldo | Club: Al-Nasr, Age: 38, birthplace: Portg |
| 3 | Xavi | Club: Barcelona, Age: 43, birthplace: Spain |

I want to parse column 'add_info' like below:

| id | name | add_info | Club | Age | birthplace |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Messi | Club: PSG, Age: 35, birthplace: Arg | PSG | 35 | Arg |
| 2 | Ronaldo | Club: Al-Nasr, Age: 38, birthplace: Portg | Al-Nasr | 38 | Portg |
| 3 | Xavi | Club: Barcelona, Age: 43, birthplace: Spain | Barcelona | 43 | Spain |

I assume that I need to use the split function and then use regular expressions to extract the values, but how to turn them into columns with values - I can't figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`str_to_map`** function to create the **`map<string,string>`** then use dynamic expression to get the items from the `map`.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'messi','Club:PSG,Age:35,birthplace:Arg')],['id','name','add_info'])

#replace spaces 
df = df.withColumn("add_info",regexp_replace(col("add_info"),'\s+',''))

df= df.withColumn("map_add_info",expr("""str_to_map(add_info,',',':')"""))

#create dynamic expression for the map_keys
cols = [col("id"), col("name")] + list(map(lambda f: col("map_add_info").getItem(f).alias(str(f)),["Club", "Age", "birthplace"]))

df.select(cols).show(10,False)
#+---+-----+----+---+----------+
#|id |name |Club|Age|birthplace|
#+---+-----+----+---+----------+
#|1  |messi|PSG |35 |Arg       |
#+---+-----+----+---+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use regex. As per the data you have provided I believe you can implement the solution by using split functions. Here is the code you may refer to, and I tested this it works fine :

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("football data").master("yarn-client").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()


df=spark.read.table("database.football_data")

df_final=df.withColumn("Club",split(split(df.add_info,",")[0],":")[1] ).withColumn("Age",split(split(df.add_info,",")[1],":")[1]).withColumn("birthplace",split(split(df.add_info,",")[2],":")[1] )

df_final.show()
```

If the add_info column is much different that what you have shared here then you can use the regex logic along with withColumn.